# How to create Swagger specification from WCF-REST API services

Tags: rest, wcf, swagger

I need to create Swagger specification from WCF-REST API services. I found a package Swagger4WCF for this purpose, but unfortunately this is not workable program, it duplicate keys and has a lot of other various errors. Is anybody know workable program for the same goal, without errors?

[image]

Comment: Using WCF-REST isn't very workable to begin with. That was only a stop-gap feature untli ASP.NET MVC/Web API came along.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. Firstly WCF-REST is more convenient an comfortable than any other method of create REST API. And secondary this is not a theoretical investigation I have workable application with millions strings of code, I need to modify it. And, of course, Microsoft opinion what is right and what is wrong in software development process is no matter at all, because goal of Microsoft is only increase software price and no more.

Comment: Saying that WCF-REST isn't workable isn't a theoretical observation either. Nor is it a Microsoft opinion. It's a developer community *verdict*. WCF-REST was a stopgap measure introduce over 10 years ago that developers themselves abandoned as soon as better options, built specifically for REST, came about. You'll have a hard time finding any good Swagger/OpenAPI packages simply because people aren't interested in building them.

Comment: Long story short, if you want to use a legacy technology with no community support, you have to support it yourself, or pay for professional support. In either case, you'll be paying to support this even if it's in time (and lost revenue)

Comment: In any case, you're asking for a library recommendation, something explicitly out of scope. If you search NuGet you'll find [just 5 packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=wcf+swagger). All except one are from 2018 or earlier. All seem to have a GitHub repo which means you can fork and fix the code if you want. The one recent package seems to be a fork of SwaggerWCF (not the one you used) to get it to work

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Dear Panagiotis, you're wrong. WCF-REST is is best technology in the world. In past 2 year I was created at least 5 project using this awesome technology. If I have right to select server technology I always select WCF REST. And my current project (rebuilding huge WCF-REST server for Android frontend) I making for $25/hour.

Comment: The facts are: 1) You're asking for a library recommendation. That's out of topic. 2) There are just 5 relevant NuGet packages. 3) The one you used has just 5K downloads and was abandoned 3 years ago. The most popular had 168K downloads but was also abandoned 3 years ago. Have you tried any of the other packages? Have you tried the [recent fork of SwaggerWCF](https://github.com/KornSW/swaggerwcf) ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation of Swagger for Wcf now. You should check this out - Swagger for WCF - [SwaggerWcf](https://github.com/abelsilva/swaggerwcf).

You can also use the [help document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-web-http-service-help-page) provided in WCF.

Comment: Swagger is the equivalent of WSDL, not the generated help page. That particular package was abandoned in 2018 and may or may not work. It was a *lot* more popular than Swagger4WCF though (168K downloads vs 5K downloads). There's [a *very* recent fork](https://github.com/KornSW/swaggerwcf) that fixes some bugs and updates package references for eg JSON.NET to recent versions